# iOS7 Pausing between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, loading, transition, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I want to call a web services during viewDidLoad. After parserDidEnd only make the viewWillAppear, is that possible?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //call webservices
    //display LOADING INDICATOR
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    //** What should I put here? **
}

-(void)viewWillAppear{
    //dismiss LOADING INDICATOR
    //continue to load screen.
}
```

Comment: You should do the loading before presenting the view. Or populate a blank page in viewWillAppear & viewDidLoad and fill it in when your parser completes. If you do what you're trying to do, you leave the user with a black screen while your parsing

Comment: Agreed, do your work before presenting the view. You have no control over when UIKit will call viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear when presenting a view.

Comment: I see, means I should call web services before navigation to this page? Thanks for advice.

Comment: @user3322987 Not necessarily. It's quite common to show the new view controller which in turns shows some sort of "Loading..." message while the data is loaded. When the load is complete, the view controller updates itself to show the loaded content.

Comment: @maddy , any example for that?